# How to check chart type on Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I noticed that parts of my code don't work for different types of charts, so I wanted to make an if else statement for that part so I could keep it for the charts that worked, and change it for the charts that didn't. For some reason, I can't figure out how to check the type of the chart.

```
let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
  type:'polarArea', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
  data:{
    labels:['Boston', 'Worcester', 'Springfield', 'Lowell', 'Cambridge', 'New Bedford'],
    datasets:[{
      label:'Employed',
      data:[
        368750,
        94941,
        60847,
        52649,
        63540,
        42322
      ],
      if(ChartType:'pie' || ChartType:'doughnut' || ChartType:'polarArea'){
        backgroundColor:[
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
      ]} else {
        backgroundColor:[
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
      ]},
```

I've also tried 'type !=', 'type:', 'chartConfig.type', etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this prop to get Chart type:

```
massPopChart.config.type
```

Comment: when I say if(massPopChart.config.type:'pie'), it returns 'types' can only be used in a .ts file

Comment: This is the only way I know how to do this. The `defaults._set` method in `controller.line.js` passes the `"line"` value as a scope to `helpers.merge`. After that, we lose the value. It would be nice if the chart controllers had a `type` or `className` field.